# Custom Validator in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes

Hey I have a simple class `UiManager` I wanna validate all variables so they should not be null

```
[SerializeField]    private    SceneLoaderManager.SceneName   gamePlaySceneName;
[SerializeField]    private    TextMeshProUGUI                coinCountUI;
[SerializeField]    private    TextMeshProUGUI                energyCountUI;
```

for now, I have only 3 variables but in the future, It can be more than 1000 I will probably validate them by checking for null but it's a lot of work to do

```
if (coinCountUi == null) Debug.Log ("you may forget to assign `CoinCountUi` ");
```

How can I validate all variables at once and throw some kind of message to the user?
I have an idea to do this but don't know how to execute it like `[WarnOnNull] [SerializeField]    private    TextMeshProUGUI                energyCountUI;` please guide me how I can create `Attribute` like this which can validate those stuff

**Part2:**

```
namespace Randoms.Reflection 
{
 [AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.All)]
 public class WarnOnNullAttribute : Attribute {}

public static class TypeChecker 
{

public static void WarnOnNull (this MonoBehaviour other) 
{
  Type type  = other.GetType ();
  
  BindingFlags bindingFlags = 
  BindingFlags.Instance  |
  BindingFlags.Public    |
  BindingFlags.NonPublic |
  BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
  
  FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type
  .GetFields (bindingFlags)
  .Where (_ => _.IsDefined (typeof (WarnOnNullAttribute),true))
  .ToArray();
  
  foreach (FieldInfo info in fieldInfos)
  {
    var val = info.GetValue (other);
    if (val == null)
      Debug.LogWarning($"{info.Name} is not referenced!");
  }
}

 }
}
```

> After `DerHugo` answer I have this code so far this code is working but still I have to write one addition line.

```
private void Awake ()
{
  this.WarnOnNull ();
}
```

how I can make this work only using attributes something like this

```
[WarnOnNull] [SerializeField]    private    TextMeshProUGUI                energyCountUI;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`How can I validate all variables at once` when exactly? On compile time these are most probably always gonna be null.

You could of course go for reflection and use a certain attribute - or simply use the existing one `SerializeField` and only check those like e.g.

```
var type = GetType();
var serializedFields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Where(field => (field.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UnityEngine.Object)) || field.FieldType == typeof(UnityEngine.Object)) && (field.IsPublic || field.IsDefined(typeof(SerializeField)))).ToArray();

foreach (var field in serializedFields)
{
    var value = field.GetValue(this);

    if (value == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{field.Name} is not referenced in {type.Name} on {this}!", this);
    }
}
```

So what does this do:

- `GetType()`: Gives us this components type
- `GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)`: Gives us all instace **fields** including those implemented by a parent type
- `(field.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UnityEngine.Object)) || field.FieldType == typeof(UnityEngine.Object))`: since we are only interested in `UnityEngine.Object` reference fields. We don't care about "normal" `Serializable` classes, strings, etc
- `(field.IsPublic || field.IsDefined(typeof(SerializeField)))`: Fields that are serialized into the Inspector are either `public` or have the attribute `[SerializeField]`

---

**Update**

As you want to use only the attribute you would need a more centralized way of calling the check method.

You can of course throw even more reflection in to simply march through all your classes.

There might be better ways to do this but this is what I came up with on my phone ^^

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class WarnOnNullAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
// Just a custom drawer to display an error if used on fields
// that are not of type UnityEngine.Object
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(WarnOnNullAttribute))]
public class WarnOnNullAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        WarnOnNullAttribute warn = attribute as WarnOnNullAttribute;

        if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference)
        {
            EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, label.text, "[WarnOnNull] is only valid on UnityEngine.Object references!", MessageType.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property);
        }
    }
}


public static class WarnOnNullAttributeCheck
{
    // This is called as soon as you open the project in Unity
    // and after script compilations
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        // Attach a listener to get notified whenever the play mode is changed
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= OnEnterPlayMode;
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += OnEnterPlayMode;

    }

    private static void OnEnterPlayMode(PlayModeStateChange state)
    {
        // only run checks once when leaving edit mode before entering play mode
        if(state != PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode) return;

        // Get all types that inherit from ScriptableObject or Component
        // as these are basically all that can have an Inspector and serialized fields
        var componentTypes = GetAllDerivedFrom(typeof(Component));
        var scriptabeObjectTypes = GetAllDerivedFrom(typeof(ScriptableObject));

        // Now we can check both lists
        // For the components we check the instances from the scene
        CheckComponents(componentTypes);
        // For the ScriptableObjects we check the assets
        CheckScriptableObjects(scriptableObjecttypes
    }

    private void CheckComponents (Type[] componentTypes)
    {
        foreach(var type in componentTypes)
        {
            // Luckily in newer Unity versions there is finally
            // a simple call to get all instances of a type from the scene
            // including even disabled/inactive ones
            var instances = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType(type, true);

            foreach(var instance in instances)
            {
                ValidateInstance (instance, type);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CheckScriptableObjects (Type[] types)
    {
        foreach(var type in types)
        {
            var instances = GetAllInstaces(type);

            foreach(var instance in instances)
            {
                ValidateInstance (instance, type);
            }
        }
    }

    private static UnityEngine.Object[] GetAllInstances(Type type)
    {
        // For ScriptableObjects we need a different approach
        // since these are assets and we need to actually load them
        var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:"+ typeof(T).Name);
        var instances = new UnityEngine.Object[guids.Length];
        for(int i =0;i<guids.Length;i++)
        {
            var path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]);
            instances[i] = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path);
        }

        return instances;
    }

    private static void ValidateInstance(UnityEngine.Object instance, Type type)
    {
        // Basically a slightly adjusted version of above
        var serializedFields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Where(field => (field.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UnityEngine.Object)) || field.FieldType == typeof(UnityEngine.Object)) && field.IsDefined(typeof(WarnOnNullAttribute)))).ToArray();

        foreach (var field in serializedFields)
        {
            var value = field.GetValue(instance);
            if (value == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"{field.Name} is not referenced for {instance}!", instance);
            }
        }
    }

     private static Type[] GetAllDerivedFrom(Type baseType)
     {
         return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
             .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
             .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType)).ToArray();
    }
}
#endif
```

It might also be possible to use `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll` instead which would even include prefabs etc but then it gets more complex and also way more expensive ;)

Comment: Hey DerHugo Cool it's working
Your question is really cool but can I use some of this like this `[WarnOnNull] public GameObject myObj` I use `Odin` inspector how they are creating custom attributes
btw thanks for the cool answer.

Comment: @Athena afaik Odin is also full of reflection and does probably something similar ;)

Comment: okay, can you see my updated question?

Comment: @Athena see the update at the bottom.. typed it on the phone so there might be issues but it should get you started ;)

Comment: Thanks for your great effort it seems like it'll work